# Linux DNS Zones Special Forwarding Condition

Tags: linux, dns, zones

We have our own DNS server but we need to get a few zone entries from a different DNS server located at a separate location. Entering these in our DNS would be tedious plus constantly changes.

The following is what I have in mind but isn't working (the.ext and IP_ADDRESS replaced of course):

```
    zone "@the.ext" {
        type stub;
        masters { IP_ADDRESS; };
};
```

The way I imagine it working is the local DNS check if the domain is "the.ext" and if so go out across the shaky VPN to get the entry and save it locally. This way if VPN is down the internet will still work.

I think my understanding of the "zone @the.ext" is wrong and I'm having a hard time looking it up. Please help! :D

Answer (score 0):

I just used the following and it worked:

```
    zone "ext" {
            type forward;
            forward only;
            forwarders { IP_ADDRESS; };
    };
```

Still not exactly sure how the "ext" part works exactly, but this worked.